# How do I downgrade Java from 1.6.0 to 1.5.0 in Ubuntu?

Tags: java

I need to downgrade Java in Ubuntu. Current version is 1.6.0, I have to use JDK 1.5.0 for my Android platform.

How to do it? Remove it and reinstall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`update-java-alternatives` is your friend:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.5.0-sun 53 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun
java-6-sun 63 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Then select the Java version you want. E.g., to seletc Java 1.5, do

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.5.0-sun
```

Make sure first that you have the correct Java packages installed.

See the [Ubuntu Java page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

Late answer but it may help someone out there:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy main multiverse"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates main multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java5-jdk
```

then you can see java5 when you

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

Comment: Very useful -- it is quite frustrating for people out here who have to support back-level software without easy access to back-level dependencies.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried all the options, including downloading from sun. None worked. This is the one that worked. Should be selected as the correct answer. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the stone age (2000-2001) on Solaris we'd install both versions side by side (/usr/local or /opt) and have a bash script to change JAVA_HOME to the version we wanted to use.  Easy peasy.  Just make sure JAVA_HOME is in your PATH and possibly your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.