# Installing Java JDK on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, java

Ever since I upgraded my Ubuntu from 9.10 to 10.04 I can't start Netbeans any more, because apparently they are dropping support for Java's JDK in favor of OpenJDK. Well, problem is, my IDEs won't work with OpenJDK.

`apt-get install sun-java6-jdk` is not working. I downloaded the Linux installation file from Sun (jdk-6u21-linux-i586.bin) and installed it, but I can't call java or javac from the terminal.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I'm voting to migrate to Super User

Comment: @David I asked it here because I figured this is something only a programmer would run into.

Comment: Well, your question is basically "How do I install <program> on <system>" which is something that belongs on Super User. The fact that the program happens to be something that's used by developers doesn't necessarily make Stack Overflow the best place for the question.

Comment: You can install JDK on Ubuntu by following the instructions here: http://kishor15389.blogspot.com/2010/11/install-jdk-on-ubuntu-any-version.html

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672795/how-do-i-downgrade-java-from-1-6-0-to-1-5-0-in-ubuntu

Comment: I would advise _not_ using the standard repo for Java development (likewise for Ruby). Manually download and install the jdk in ~/opt/jdk/jdk1.7.0_xx. You can point NetBeans or any of the other major IDEs to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes#Sun%20Java%20moved%20to%20the%20Partner%20repository) is how you would install it.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6
```

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work any more - Canonical pulled Java from the partner repo over licensing issues. There is a good PPA that is currently well-maintained: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Answer (score 3):

[How to install Java6 JDK on Ubuntu 10.04](http://happy-coding.com/install-sun-java6-jdk-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Answer (score 2):

The NetBeans installation has a reference to the JDK that is created at install time. After the upgrade to 10.04, that reference is no longer valid.

Go to the directory where you installed NetBeans. By default it is "/usr/local/netbeans-*version*" if you installed as root or "$HOME/netbeans-*version*" if you installed as a regular user. There will be a subdirectory named "etc". In that directory, edit the "netbeans.conf" file. Look for the `netbeans_jdk_home` and change it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk`.

Comment: +1 though it's too late for that. I managed to install the official SDK. I don't think the OpenJDK should even exist, but that's another discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded the Linux installation file from Sun (jdk-6u21-linux-i586.bin) and installed it, but I can't call java or javac from the terminal.

You missed the final step: after installing the JDK manually (instead of from the package system), you need to add the `bin` directory of your JDK to the `PATH`. The best way to do that in Ubuntu 10.04 is to edit the file `/etc/environment`: `sudo nano /etc/environment`. Log out and back in and you should be able to run Java.

Answer (score 0):

To run add-apt-repository, you need to install `python-software-properties` first. If you don't want to do this, you can:

1. Edit the sources.list file. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Uncomment the lines `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner` and `deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner` (they are the second set from teh bottom)
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. And finally, `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is no longer in the partner repo. You can download the binaries directly from Oracle, but much easier is to use the the Web Upd8 PPA. Complete instructions are [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Sun JDK on Ubuntu Visit following source.

http://peesquare.com/blogs/install-sun-java-6-on-ubuntu-10-04-12-04-12-10-13-04-13-10-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-system/